# Comparing values in a panda dataframe and returning new value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe like this:

```
         date        id      tier
0      2020-06-02    23      3
1      2020-06-02    23      2
2      2020-06-02    23      1
3      2020-06-02    7       3
23026  2020-06-20     7      3
41740  2020-07-07    9       3
```

I want to make a new column from 'tier' whose values are 0, if the former values is the same as the present value or there is no former value, 1 if the former value is more than the present value and -1 every other case, like this:

```
         date        id      tier  move
0      2020-06-02    23      3      0
1      2020-06-02    23      2      1
2      2020-06-02    23      1      1
3      2020-06-02    23      3      -1
23026  2020-06-20     7      3       0
41740  2020-07-07    9       3       0
```

I have tried .shift() mostly, as per SO answers I was, but to no avail. When I do:

```
if df['tier'].shift() < df['tier']:
  df['Movement'] = -1
elif df['tier'].shift() == df['tier']:
  df['Movement'] = 0
else:
  df['Movement'] = 1
```

It wails about DF not being the same shape 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (78792,) (385,2)'
But there is only one df being use, dont know if my code is bad or where does that (385,2)  come from
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np
conditions=[df['tier'].shift().fillna(df['tier']).eq(df['tier']),
            df['tier'].shift().fillna(df['tier']).gt(df['tier'])]
choices=[0,1]

df['move']=np.select(conditions, choices, default=-1)
```

Output:

```
df
             date  id  tier  move
0      2020-06-02  23     3     0
1      2020-06-02  23     2     1
2      2020-06-02  23     1     1
3      2020-06-02   7     3    -1
23026  2020-06-20   7     3     0
41740  2020-07-07   9     3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff) and [`series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html?highlight=series%20clip#pandas.Series.clip):

```
>>> df.assign(move= (-df.tier.diff(1)).fillna(0).clip(-1,1).astype(int))
             date  id  tier  move
0      2020-06-02  23     3     0
1      2020-06-02  23     2     1
2      2020-06-02  23     1     1
3      2020-06-02   7     3    -1
23026  2020-06-20   7     3     0
41740  2020-07-07   9     3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `np.sign` on the negative of the `diff`:

```
df['move'] = np.sign(-df['tier'].diff().fillna(0))
             date  id  tier  move
0      2020-06-02  23     3   0.0
1      2020-06-02  23     2   1.0
2      2020-06-02  23     1   1.0
3      2020-06-02   7     3  -1.0
23026  2020-06-20   7     3   0.0
41740  2020-07-07   9     3   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

vectorised `np.where` works well

```
import numpy as np
data = """rid         date        id      tier
0      2020-06-02    23      3
1      2020-06-02    23      2
2      2020-06-02    23      1
3      2020-06-02    7       3
23026  2020-06-20     7      3
41740  2020-07-07    9       3"""
a = [[t for t in l.split(" ") if t!=""]  for l in data.split("\n")]
df = ( pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
 .astype({"id":"int64","rid":"int64","tier":"int64","date":"datetime64"})
 .set_index("rid")
)
df.assign(move=lambda dfa: 
          np.where(dfa["tier"].shift()<dfa["tier"], -1, 
                  np.where(dfa["tier"].shift()>dfa["tier"], 1, 0))
         )
```